# CIFilter to composite 2 CIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, cifilter, ciimage

I want to make a iOS camera App. The app should allow user to select a image from photos gallery and be combined with the output data from the camera to create a side my side type of effect. I also want the image that the user have selected to be recorded to the video output. The process should be done in realtime because i want to have a video output. What approach should I take?
Thank you

Comment: I need this for realtime processing with CMBuffer from the camera. Wouldn't drawing be a consume of resources? Is there anyway to use the GPU?

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you for replying.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the problem. Why not display an image view on one side and the camera video layer on the other side? It seems so simple. There is no "process" involved.

Comment: I also want the image that the user have selected to be recorded to the video output.

Comment: Very good info. Again, I suggest you incorporate that into your question. (I'm sorry I'm not actually giving an answer, so I hope you don't mind my suggestions for clarifying the question! I'm trying to hone the question so that an expert can discover and answer it. :)